# in ruby how do I add objects to an array, keep a counter for every object and still check easily if the object is in the array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to compile a list of recommended friends.

What I was thinking was something like this (this is semi pseudo (sudo) code!):

```
recommended_friends = []
friends.each do |friend|
   while recommeded_friends.length < 10
      friend.friends.each do |friend|
         if friend.in?(recommeded_friends)
             recommeded_friends[friend][counter] += 1
         else
             recommeded_friends << [friend, 0]
         end
      end
    end
end
```

But this obviously doesn't work. How would you guys approach this?

Thanks for any suggestions.

The tables (some are shortened):

```
Users:
id | name 

Friendships
id | user_1_id | user_2_id | requested_at | accepted_at | declined_at |
```

A friendship between user1 and user2 only occurs once in the DB.

Comment: you are missing the count  method, recommended_friends.count <10. Also it seems you have totally confused your array here to such a extent that even iam confused what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: Do you mean "semi pseudo code"?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Haha yes of course I do... This is me typing while being  fuelled by  RAGE! ;)

Comment: @Stefano Make sure you don't use `sudo` while fuelled by rage!

Comment: @AndrewGrimm I will try to keep that in mind :D

Comment: Isn't that a bad idea to use the same name for two do-blocks? I mean "do |friend|"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATED.
Try something like this, it should work:

```
recommended_friends = {}
friends.each do |friend|
   if recommeded_friends.length < 10
      friend.friends.each do |other_friend|
         if other_friend != this_user          # exclude myself 
           recommeded_friends[other_friend] =
             (recommeded_friends[other_friend] | 0) + 1
         end
      end
   end
end
recommendend_friends.sort_by{|key, value| value}.reverse
top_ten = recommended_friends.first(10).map{|a| a[0]}
```

SQL version:

```
Users.find_by_sql([
  "SELECT u.*
   FROM 
   (SELECT f2.id, f2.user_1_id u_1_id, f2.user_2_id u_2_id, (count(f1.id)) cnt
      FROM friendships f1 
      JOIN friendships f2 ON f1.user_1_id = f2.user_1_id
                          OR f1.user_2_id = f2.user_1_id
                          OR f1.user_2_id = f2.user_2_id
                          OR f1.user_1_id = f2.user_2_id
      WHERE (f1.user_1_id = ? OR f1.user_2_id = ?)
        AND (f2.user_1_id <> ? AND f2.user_2_id <> ?)
      GROUP BY f2.id, f2.user_1_id, f.user_2_id
      HAVING count(f2.id) = 1
      ORDER BY cnt DESC) fs
   JOIN friendships ff ON ff.user_1_id = fs.u_1_id
                       OR ff.user_2_id = fs.u_1_id
                       OR ff.user_2_id = fs.u_2_id
                       OR ff.user_1_id = fs.u_2_id
   JOIN users u ON 
     CASE WHEN (ff.user_1_id = fs.u_1_id OR ff.user_2_id = fs.u_1_id) 
                THEN fs.u_2_id ELSE fs.u_1_id END = u.id ", 
 user.id, user.id, user.id, user.id]).first(10)
```

In theory it should work, take a try.

Comment: I want 10 friends, and rank them according to how many friends they have in common. I know that the DB is better for this kind of stuff but I am no database architect.

Comment: Then this loop won't work properly. I'll write a better solution soon.

Comment: I will try your answer later today. But you are right about doing this in the DB being better. How would one do that though? After a little bit of Join here and join there my SQL knowledge is exhausted.

Comment: If you provide some table names, then I might write SQL for you. Actually it only needs some join and group by.

Comment: Done so, check my question. Is pretty straight forward for someone who knows a bit of SQL I imagine.

Comment: I had to fix a little typo `(count f1.id)` didn't work so I had to make `count(f1.id)`. But it gets stuck on the GROUP_BY `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "GROUP_BY"
LINE 8:                GROUP_BY f2.id, f2.user_1_id, f.user_2_id`

Comment: My bad, no underscore needed in that. The correct is `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`, corrected in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

recommeded_friends will always stay an empty array.
You can not do this: recommeded_friends < 10

Try this: recommeded_friends.length < 10

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method I can think of:

```
 recommended_friends = friend.friends.sort do |a,b|
   a <=> b # insert your ranking algorithm here
 end.take 10
```